# Intersecting closedness property proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

A set A is said to be having the intersecting closedness property if it satisfies this condition: If S is any collection of closed sets for which the intersection of any finite number of sets from S contains an element of A, then the intersection of every set in S also contains an element of A. Prove that A has the intersecting closedness property if and only if A is compact.

Hint: consider the complements of the sets in S.

For the question above, my attempt is as follows:
Since the intersection for finite amount of S contains A, then S_bar is a collection of open set. This open set is a finite open cover of A. Since the choice of S is arbitrary,  and S_bar has finite subcover, I got the conclusion that A_bar is compact, therefore A cannot be compact.

What is wrong with my proof? And, could anyone give me hints on how to use the Hint given above?

Comment: Welcome. What is the meaning of "-bar"? If you mean the closure, then $\overline{A}$ being compact can still mean that $A$ is compact, I don't see what the objection is. As for the exercise, I strongly suspect that you should just mimic the proof of the finite intersection property criterion for compactness

Comment: Thanks! I'm heading down to prove that S = A. Is this correct?

Comment: No, $S$ could be any arbitrary family of closed sets, and need not equal $A$. It need not be contained in, or contain, $A$ either.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be compact and $S$ be a collection of closed sets such that any finite intersection of elements in $S$ contains an element of $A$. Suppose by contradiction that there exists a sub-collection $\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$ is disjoint from $A$ (notice that such a collection must be infinite), then the complement $\bigcup C_\alpha^c$ is an open cover for $A$, since $A$ is compact there exists a finite subcover $C_1^c,\ldots,C_n^c$ (after re-indexing) such that
$A\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n C_j^c$, reversing the inclusion gives a contradiction, since $C_1,\ldots,C_n\in S$ is a finite family from $S$ whose intersection is disjoint from $A$.

Viceversa suppose $A$ has the intersecting closedness property. Again by contradiction: suppose $A$ is not compact, then there exists an open cover $\mathcal{U}=\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $A$ such that no finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ cover entirely $A$.

Let $S:=\{C_\alpha=U_\alpha^c\}_{\alpha \in I}$, then any finite intersection of element in $S$ contains an element of $A$, by the intersecting closedness property so does ANY intersection of element in $S%$, in particular, if $\mathcal{C}=\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} C_\alpha$, then there exists $a\in A\cap \mathcal{C}$ which implies

$$a\notin \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha$$

i.e. $\mathcal{U}$ is not an open cover for $A$.